# Galaxy S4 - Bluetooth Low Energy Peripheral Mode?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am currently working on an Android project that requires Bluetooth Low Energy Peripheral mode. As of now, just targeting the Galaxy S4 with 4.2.2 on it Samsung BLE SDK at http://developer.samsung.com/ble

I followed their API docs and programming guide very closely, however broadcasting characteristics or services over Bluetooth Low Energy just doesn't seem to work. Has anyone else had any luck with getting this to work yet? If so, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try the BlePXPMonitor code? Once you connect to your BLE device it should start Service Discovery and you should at least see some output for that in the ADB log.

Answer (score 1):

Because Samsung BLE  SDK only supports the central role, “advertising” a service as a central server means sitting their quietly, only revealing (or “advertising”) its service characteristics to another device in peripheral mode after a connection is already established. This connection establishment requires another device to do the actual radio advertising first. Samsung’s SDK isn’t going to do it.

What we need is an Android BLE API that allows creation of a peripheral server. Lots of folks were hoping that peripheral role support would be added in 4.4, but it wasn’t. Maybe we can hope for its addition in Android 4.5 or 5.0. There is a feature request asking for this. Add your name to the list!

[Source](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/12/15/why-android-devices-cant-act-as-ibeacons.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same issue. I can discover BLE devices and get their rssi values, but when I try to discover services or connect, I never receive a callback. I am using a Verizon Galaxy S4 running 4.2.2. I am using the Samsung BLE SDK 2.0. Apparently some heart rate monitors are working, but I get nothing using my ez430-rf256x TI development kit. I've tried the Keyfob demo and Heart Rate Profile demo in the Bluetopia v1.3 sdk.

Comment: teepsdonnelly, what kind of ble device are you trying to connect? Are you implementing a custom profile or using a standard one such as the heart rate profile?

Answer (score 0):

Phones/tablets/pc's support(usually) Bluetooth dual mode chip. According to Bluetooth specification dual mode devices can't be a peripheral, but single mode devices do.